# Select checkbox pass array in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

How can I pass the value of array? of the selected checkbox.

In View:

```
= check_box_tag 'user_message_ids[]', user_message.id, false

= link_to "<button>Bulk Delete</button>".html_safe, profile_message_path(user_message), :id => 'user_message_ids', :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete
```

and can I place the submit button in any of this area.

like this one:

```
= form_tag checked_messages_path do
  = check_box_tag 'user_message_ids[]', user_message.id, false
--------objects---------------------------------------------
--------objects---------------------------------------------
--------objects---------------------------------------------
--------objects---------------------------------------------
= submit_tag "Delete Checked"
```

Answer (score 20):

Use a `form_tag` block

```
<% form_tag delete_mutiple_items_path do %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "items[]", item.id %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag "delete Checked" %>
<% end %>
```

It will pass an array of ids to controller, like {"item_ids[]" => ["1", "2", "3"]}

So you can do anything with these ids

FYI: http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple?view=asciicast

#### Updated (One Small Gotcha)

From here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast

> There is still one small problem with our update method. **If we uncheck all of the checkboxes to remove a product from all categories then the update fails** to remove any categories the product was in. This is because a checkbox on an HTML form will not have its value sent back if it is unchecked and therefore no `category_ids` will appear in the product’s parameters hash, meaning that the `category_ids` are not updated.
>
> To fix this **we have to modify our products controller** to set the `category_ids` parameter to be an empty array if it is not passed to the update action. We can do this using `Ruby's ||=` operator and add the following like at the top of the update action.
>
> `params[:product][:category_ids] ||= []`
>
> This will ensure that if none of the checkboxes are checked then the product is updated correctly so that it is in no categories.

Comment: Thnx, I think this may help me. GodBless

Comment: suggestions for Select and unselect all checkbox?

Comment: I see a problem here and it is that if none `check_box` is selected the update will not modify the entity, because the _array param_ will not be sent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the button tag around a form tag. You cannot submit input tag data using a `link_to`.

Comment: but I need to place the button on the top of objects and its not working... any more advice?