# Filtering using Scopes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, filtering

I'm trying to create a records filtering system using ActiveRecord scopes but i am stuck at the point where you have two filters of the same model. I am trying to filter products with `brand_id: 1` and `brand_id:2`

My `Product` model with the `brand` scope defined looks like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand

  scope :brand, lambda{|brand| where('brand_id = ?', brand )}
end
```

I am trying to filter the products on my `categories/show` view and the `CategoriesController` looks like this:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  has_scope :brand

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @products_by_category = apply_scopes(Product).where(category_id: @category).load
    @brands = @category.brands
  end
end
```

The `categories/show` view looks like this:

```
<% @products_by_category.each do |product| %>
  <h2><%= product.name %></h2>
<% end %>
```

i am using this form to do the filtering:

```
<%= form_tag @category_path, method: get do %>
  <% @brands.each do |brand| %>
    <span class="filter_name"><%= brand.name%>:</span>
    <span> <%= check_box_tag :brand, brand.id, false,
                                     class: 'filter_check_box' %> </span>

   <% end %>
  <%=submit_tag 'filter'%>
<% end %>
```

The problem is when i select more than one brand in the check_boxes, it filters the products with only the first parameter;

for example if i filter with brands with `:id 1` and `:id 2` and submits the form,
it the request url looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/categories/1?&brand=1&brand=4`
and the queried array is only filtered with `brand=1`. I would like the results to be filtered by both parameters. Is the resulting url even correct or should it be:
`http://localhost:3000/categories/1?&brand=1,4` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the filter inputs you are submitting have the same parameters key, `brand`. So, the parameters hash can only have one value for that key.

You want to use a check_box_tag instead for `'brand_ids[]'`:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'brand_ids[]', brand.id, false, class: 'filter_check_box' %>
```

Finally, **and this is important**, you cannot send an array to the parameters via a GET action. You will need to use a POST. As the second link below notes, this is a limitation of HTTP, not Rails.

See also:

- [Select checkbox pass array in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965248/select-checkbox-pass-array-in-ruby-on-rails)
- [Passing array of parameters through get in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312930/passing-array-of-parameters-through-get-in-rails)

**Aside**

I would humbly recommend you refer to variables with more consistent names, for ease of readability and maintenance of code. If you're using a brand_id, as in that Product scope, call it a brand_id, not a brand.

Comment: It is still not working, it is passing `brand_ids[]` as a single parameter instead of an array of brand_ids. Isn't the parameter supposed to match the name of the scope?

Comment: I added a comment on the limit of GET in sending parameters, after having reviewed more closely your form setup and the problem you're having.

Comment: Your second link has informed me what i need to know, I'll therefore accept your answer.