# check_box_tag doesn't pass any parameter if not checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to have an if else statement in the controller to do something if the `check_box_tag` is checked and something else if it isn't checked.

```
<%= check_box_tag "apply[]", 1, false %>
```

If it is checked and the form is submitted `"apply"=>["1"]` is passed as a parameter, if it isn't checked nothing is sent.

Can I have a `"apply"=>["0"]` passed as a param if it isn't checked?

Answer (score 2):

The `check_box_tag` indeed [does not use the hidden field](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L372) so it does not send anything in case the box is unchecked (unlike the `check_box` helper, which is nevertheless still not useful in case of an array param, as Meier notes above).

If you are trying to use your checkbox in a similar way as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965314/1544012) (i.e. to send a user-selected array of ids for example), the simple solution might be to react on an empty param in the controller. Something in the way of:

```
params[:apply] ||= []
```

If, on the other hand, you wanted to use the checkboxes as an ordered array where each value would be determined by its constant position in the array, either true or false, (i.e. if you wanted to get something like this in the `apply` param: `[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`), this wouldn't work. You'd have to choose a different approach, e.g. use the checkboxes with a hash param instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

The rails guide has a warning box about this special case:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

> Array parameters do not play well with the check_box helper. According
>   to the HTML specification unchecked checkboxes submit no value.
>
> However it is often convenient for a checkbox to always submit a
>   value. The check_box helper fakes this by creating an auxiliary hidden
>   input with the same name. If the checkbox is unchecked only the hidden
>   input is submitted and if it is checked then both are submitted but
>   the value submitted by the checkbox takes precedence. When working
>   with array parameters this duplicate submission will confuse Rails
>   since duplicate input names are how it decides when to start a new
>   array element. It is preferable to either use check_box_tag or to use
>   hashes instead of arrays.

Comment: This line confuses me 'It is preferable to either use check_box_tag or to use hashes instead of arrays.' I feel like its saying it is preferable to use `check_box_tag` because it will send a param for both checked and un checked. But it doesn't...